# install mysql workbench xubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I am new xubuntu user and I was looking to install mysql workbench.  I tried installing the Ubuntu distribution for Workbench but it did not install.

Are there any alternatives for mysql workbench?

Comment: MySQL Workbench is supported on Linux: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-linux.html ... but you can also use the command line as an alternative.

Comment: I cannot seem to find support for Xubuntu

Comment: From Wikipedia: `Xubuntu is a Canonical Ltd.–recognized, community-maintained derivative of the Ubuntu operating system` ... my guess is that most programs which run on Ubuntu would run on XUbuntu.  Have you tried installing Workbench yet?

Comment: Yes I tried the ubuntu version which doesn't install so I was looking if there is any specific version for Xubuntu @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: The ubuntu version I was trying to install from the software installer but it just didn't install. So there wasn't any specific error I can tell you

Comment: Did you try using `yum` or was it through some other means?

Comment: I have managed to install it through apt-get. It was missing dependencies which I downloaded and it seems to be working now. Thank you @TimBeigeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran **dpkg -i [Package name]** it showed there were missing dependencies.
I installed the dependencies using **apt-get**.

Once all the dependencies were installed I ran **dpkg -i [Package name]** again. Now mysql-workbench is installed :D